# Display multiple subtype objects in one page

Tags: php, beginner, object-oriented

I have a base class and 3 sub-classes:
`Item` <-- `Book`, `MusicCD`, `Software`

They have some common and different properties but in the view I want to get a mixed list of them and show in one table, with these columns headers:

> Title  Price  Volume  Author  Artist  Edition  Version

Classes:

```
abstract class Item {
    protected $id;
    protected $title;
    protected $price;
    function getTitle() { return $this->title; }
    function getPrice() { return $this->price; }
    function getAuthor() { return ''; }
    function getEdition() { return ''; }
    function getVolume() { return ''; }
    function getArtist() { return ''; }
    function getVersion() { return ''; }
}
class Book extends Item {
    private $author;
    private $edition;
    private $volume;
    function getAuthor() { return $this->author; }
    function getEdition() { return $this->edition; }
    function getVolume() { return $this->volume; }
}
class MusicCd extends Item {
    private $artist;
    private $volume;
    function getArtist() { return $this->artist; }
    function getVolume() { return $this->volume; }
}
class Software extends Item {
    private $version;
    function getVersion() { return $this->version; }
}
```

View:

```
<?php
// The controller pass items to view
$items = $this->items;
?>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Title</th><th>Price</th><th>Volume</th><th>Author</th><th>Artist</th><th>Edition</th><th>Version</th>
</tr>
<?php
foreach ($items as $i) :
?>
<tr>
<td><?=$i->getTitle()?></td>
<td><?=$i->getPrice()?></td>
<td><?=$i->getVolume()?></td>
<td><?=$i->getAuthor()?></td>
<td><?=$i->getArtist()?></td>
<td><?=$i->getEdition()?></td>
<td><?=$i->getVersion()?></td>
</tr>
<?php
endforeach;
?>
</table>
```

I feel that the classes seem not good enough because if more subtypes appear, I will probably have to modify the `Item` class. How can I improve that?

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Code Review!  You seem to be asking about code not yet written, which is off-topic for Code Review.  You could write it both ways and ask for a [tag:comparative-review].  Alternately, you could try changing the question to fit Programmers.SE or Stack Overflow.  P.S.  Rather than concatenating the results of methods that may or may not exist, I would give `Item` a [`__toString`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) method and just write `echo $i . "\n";` or `echo "$i\n";`.

Comment: @Brythan Thank you. I've read the Help and still haven't got the on/off-topic much. I will try more. In the meantime I will edit the question to be more complete with the code.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to manipulate the objects in the `$items` list, but simply want to output them to the screen, use the **[__toString()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring)** method. For `Book` this would be:

```
public function __toString()
{
    $result = $this->getTitle() . '  ' .
              $this->getPrice() . '  ' .
              $this->getVolume() . '  ' .
              $this->getAuthor() . '  ' .
              . '    ' .  //Here comes 'artist'
              $this->getEdition() . '  '
    return $result;
}
```

And then do this for the other class as well. This is not the most ideal situation because when you want to change the order of the properties for the output, you'll have to change the method in all the derived classes. There's not magic automated way to do this I believe.

Comment: Thank you. The change in the view is exactly what I worry about. Anyway, I will edit the question so that it is more clear.

Comment: I hope you'll find a fix for this, like I said.. I don't think there's aan easy automated way to do this.